# Swift expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: xcode, swift, arc4random, cgfloat

I'm having an error when compiling a project in Xcode, it says:

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

here's the code:

```
static func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()/0xFFFFFFFF) * (max - min) + min)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not reduce the complexity for the compiler by breaking the expression down into two sub-expressions?

```
static func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let rand = CGFloat(arc4random()/0xFFFFFFFF)
    return (rand * (max - min) + min)
}
```

You can also use `UINT32_MAX` (or the more "Swifty" `UInt32.max` or `.max`) in place of `0xFFFFFFFF` to improve readability.  If I recall, `0xFFFFFFFF` is the hex value of the max value of an unsigned 32-bit Integer as defined in the `<stdint.h>` header.

```
#define UINT32_MAX 0xffffffff  /* 4294967295U */
```

Comment: I think this misses the point (or at least the question I wanted answered!): what does that compiler error mean???

Comment: What do you think it means?  The expression was too complex for the compiler, and it timed out trying to resolve the `+` and `*` operator overloads: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1097960#1097960

Comment: Ah! Overload resolution.  Got it.

Comment: `UInt32.max` is a bit more Swift-y: `let rand = CGFloat(arc4random() / .max)`

Comment: @Stuart great point! Edited my answer to also include this style option.